# Quando utilizar querySelector ao invés de getElementById?

Tags: javascript

Busquei algumas informações na internet sobre isso já, inclusive no SOen, entretanto ainda não consegui chegar a uma conclusão exata.

Devo apontar que a questão não se refere somente a performance, mas a situações inusitadas e boas práticas.

Enfim. Fazer

```
document.getElementById('teste');
```

ou

```
document.querySelector("#teste");
```

retorna a mesma coisa. Sei que o `getElementById` é aproximadamente 5x mais rápido, mas acredito que existam situações onde o uso do `querySelector` seriam melhores. Legibilidade talvez?

Se `getElementById` é mais rápido, em quais situações o `querySelector` se prova uma melhor opção?

Obs.: a questão se refere apenas ao caso de captura de IDs.

Comment: Por curiosidade: por que o `getElementById` é aprox. 5x mais rápido? Tem algum lugar que eu possa ver sobre isso? Eu até imagino que deva existir outra estrutura separada com os _ids_, mas não vejo motivo para o `querySelector` não fazer uso dessa estrutura sendo que pode-se identificar facilmente quando o seletor é um id.

Comment: [getElementById vs. getElementsByClassName vs. querySelector vs. jQuery](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/25) executado no meu navegador: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZA2u.png. Nada absoluto, mas são alguns números.

Comment: "Sei que o getElementById é aproximadamente 5x mais rápido" - Tem alguma fonte / benchmarks a suportar esta afirmação ?

Comment: @Isac Li isso em alguns locais, incluindo no SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046356/performance-using-js-queryselector
mas não posso afirmar ser uma fonte totalmente confiável, então estejam livres para me corrigir.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Além da performance envolvida (`getElementById` é um pouco mais performático, irei citar alguns testes mais abaixo) podemos considerar:

**QuerySelector**

A vantagem de seu uso, ao contrário de `document.getElementById`,  `document.querySelector` pode retornar classes, além disso, é possível usar `seletores` `CSS`, o que não é possível fazer com o `getElementById`.

Exemplo:

`document.querySelector("#element a[target]");`

```js
document.querySelector("#element a[target]").style.color = 'green';
```

```html
<span id="element"> <a href="#" target="_blank"> link com target </a> </span>
```

Que tal uma seleção mais avançada?

`document.querySelector("#element ul li:nth-child(2)").style.color = "blue";`

```js
document.querySelector("#element ul li:nth-child(2)").style.color = "blue";
```

```html
<div id="element">
    <ul>
        <li> Item 1 </li>
        <li> Item 2 - Alvo </li>
        <li> Item 3 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Vale lembrar que o `querySelector` irá pegar apenas o primeiro `elemento` que for encontrado no documento.

no exemplo abaixo, apenas no primeiro `item` foi aplicado o `CSS`:

```js
document.querySelector('span, p').style.color='lightblue';
```

```html
<span>[span] -  Aqui será aplicado </span> <br>
<span>[span] -  Aqui não será aplicado </span>  

<p>[p] -  Aqui não será aplicado </p>
```

Se for preciso realizar a seleção de múltiplos elementos, utilize `querySelectorAll` que irá retornar um objeto `NodeList`, para aplicar os estilos em todos, basta aplicar um loop como no exemplo abaixo:

```js
//selecionando todos os elementos span e p
let obj = document.querySelectorAll('span, p'); 

console.log("tipo: " + typeof obj);
console.log("Quantidade: " +obj.length);

//aplicando o estilo em todos os elementos selecionados
for(let i of obj) {  
    i.style.color= "blue";
}
```

```html
<span>[span] -  Aqui será aplicado </span> <br>
<span>[span] -  Aqui também será aplicado </span> 
<p>[p] -  Aqui também será aplicado </p>
```

**getElementById**

O mesmo é um pouco mais performático do que o `querySelector` e pode ser visto nesse teste [aqui](https://esbench.com/bench/57bdc462db965b9a00965c70) e nesse [aqui](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector-vs-queryselector-by-id) também.

Acredito que o seu uso deve ser feito sempre que for preciso selecionar um elemento pelo `id`, uma seleção como o exemplo abaixo, considero inviável pelo fato de existir uma função específica para buscas por `identificadores`.

Exemplo inviável :

`document.querySelector("[id=elemento]");`

**Conclusão**

Se precisas selecionar apenas um elemento pelo `identificador`, é mais viável utlizar `document.getElementById` pois o mesmo é específico para essa finalidade, caso precise usar uma seleção mais precisa/avançada, use `document.querySelector` pelo fato de ter a liberdade de utilizar seletores `CSS`, o que é uma grande vantagem.

Nada impede de usares `querySelector` para selecionar um elemento pelo `id`, além do mais, dificilmente uma aplicação sofrerá de baixa performance por conta disso.

Comment: Boa resposta.
Vou esperar para ver se mais alguma aparece com mais informações, caso contrário marco a sua como aceita.

Comment: Ainda tenho a intenção de realizar alguns reajustes.

Comment: Acho que agora está ok.